# c# Asp.net Web API Attribute Routing 404 Error

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-web-api-routing

I cannot figure out why one my attribute routing isn't working, the first action method works but not the second one.

Here is my setup:

```
public class ActivMobileController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/ActivMobile/Impact/{token}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Impact(string token)
    {
     ...   
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/ActivMobile/Attachments/{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Attachments(string id)
    {
     ...
    }
 }
```

here is my WebApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api
        config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("AllowOrigins"), "*", "*"));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the URL im testing and it gives 404 Error

http://localhost:60105/api/ActivMobile/Attachments/39E522838A652508112E9AD1E0E831C7

Comment: See My answer please remember to upvote and mark as correct if this fixes your problem

Comment: @johnny5 it did not fix it, I cant think of anything that im missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're specifying API twice when it's already in your default template

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Remove the redundant Api/activMobile from your routes

```
[Route("Impact/{token}")]
public IHttpActionResult Impact(string token)
{
 ...   
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("Attachments/{id}")]
public IHttpActionResult Attachments(string id)
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: it did not work, I dont think that could be the issue since when I call the other API method: http://localhost:60105/api/ActivMobile/Impact/39E522838A652508112E9AD1E0E831C7 it works perfectly